# Add shadow to MarkerComposable of Google Maps in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I have a map implemented with Google Maps and I use a MarkerComposable to create a custom marker. So far, so good. But I need to add a small elevation with its shadow, and even though I pass it as a modifier, on the map it appears without the shadow.
If I do it on a surface, the shadow is shown, so could it be that the GoogleMap composable doesn't allow adding shadows to markers?

I have seen this pending issue: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/398

Thanks in advance!

```
// ...
    MarkerComposable(
        keys = arrayOf(isSelected),
        state = MarkerState(location.toLatLng()),
        onClick = { _ ->
            onMarkerClick()
            false
        },
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(painter),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.shadow(elevation = 5.dp) // Doesn't show the shadow
        )
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try using  the [AdvancedMarker](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-advanced-marker.html) for your custom marker?

Comment: I need to use de MarkerComposable to create my own design